# Instantly Updating a field in a FireStore document

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to instantly update a field of a Firestore document. Here's my code:

```
func updatingNumGames() {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        
        db.collection("users").document("\(email)").getDocument { snapshot, error in
            guard let data = snapshot?.data(),
                error == nil else {
                    return
                }
            
            var gamesPlayed: Int = 0
            
            //updatting numGames played
            if let fsNumGamesPlayed = data["numGamesPlayed"] as? Int {
                 gamesPlayed = fsNumGamesPlayed
            }
            
            print("gamesPlayed:", gamesPlayed)
            
            let docRef = db.collection("users").document(email)
            
            docRef.setData([
                "numGamesPlayed": gamesPlayed + 1
            ], merge: true) { error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error updating document: \(error)")
                } else {
                    let numGamesPlayedd = data["numGamesPlayed"] as! Int
                    
                    print("Document updated successfully: \(numGamesPlayedd)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to instantly update the "numGamesPlayed" field, specifically incrementing the Int value in the field by one. I need the field to be updated immediately because I want to immediately reflect the update in my UI, but I haven't been able to find any successful method for doing this (ChatGPT said adding in the 'merge: true' argument to the 'set' function would instantly update the field, but that didn't work).

Comment: If you want to increment a field in a document, have a look at the documentaiton here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#swift_13

Comment: I'm not having trouble with the incrementation part. What I'm having trouble with is making the update to a data field instantly. For example, in the simulator I'll update the data field, but because it's asynchronous it won't update instantly - I'll have to restart the app before I can see the change in the data field. I'm trying to figure out a way for the change in the field to be instant.

Comment: The change to the database *is* instant, but your code is not listening for updates (as far as I can see). To make it listen for updates, use `addSnapshotListener` instead of `getDocument ` as shown in https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#swift